# Mopidy Node-Red Node cannot play Spotify tracks or albums

Tags: spotify, node-red, mopidy

Has anyone succeeded in playing Spotify tracks or albums via Node-Red Mopidy node? I tryed to follow the example [here](https://github.com/emiloberg/node-red-contrib-mopidy) using these three nodes: `tracklist.clear` + `tracklist.add` + `playback.play` with the following options without any success:

`https://open.spotify.com/track/5WvAo7DNuPRmk4APhdPzi8`

`spotify:track:5WvAo7DNuPRmk4APhdPzi8`

Am I selecting the right link types or syntaxes? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't succeed at all with that node. The code is deprecated and a lot of abandoned modules are loaded. It should be upgraded but the author is no more working on it.